# ReactJS Parent not rendering Children

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, reactjs

Using [backbone-react-component](https://github.com/magalhas/backbone-react-component/blob/master/examples/nested/nested.jsx) I am trying to build a task list of sorts. If you look at the snipplet provided you will see to core variables `tasksList` and `tasksListChild` of which my code thus far seems to render as far as `_createTaskChild` But Rendering beyond that I have nothing, literally, not even an error in the console window. I put `console.log` to better elaborate here where things are kind of failing?.. `console.log(model.get('task_id'));` will put out to the console no problem.  `console.log('hi')` however, does not. I'm hoping by coming here an extra set of eyes can tell me where I messed up.

```
var tasksListChild = React.createClass({
    mixins: [BackboneReactMixin],
    render: function () {
        console.log('hi')
        return (
            <span onClick={ this._handleTaskClick }>nothing</span>
        );
    },
    _handleTaskClick: function (event) {
        console.log(this.props)
    }
});


var tasksList = React.createClass({
    mixins: [BackboneReactMixin],
    render: function () {
        return (
            <div className="list-group js__page-list-group-tasks">
            {
                this.getCollection().map(this._createTaskChild)
            }
            </div>
        );
    },
    _createTaskChild: function (model) {
        console.log(model.get('task_id'));
        return (
        <a className="list-group-item">
            <tasksListChild key={model.get('task_id')} model={model} />
        </a>
        );
    }
});
```

Comment: What does this.getCollection() return an array of?

Comment: Its functionality the mixin offers to bridge react and backbone. As I understand it, it takes the collection thats passed to react, and attaches listeners to it that will work with react. But in the same token in this scenario its supposed to take the collection passed and using map to break it into individual models for each child view in this case, assuming my understanding is correct

Comment: You need to know what getCollection is returning so you know what you are mapping. The key={model.get('task_id')} is suggesting that the object has a get function embedded in it. That is uncommon.

Comment: Uncommon yes, natively. But we are using Backbone as well, which is where that functionality is embedded. The mixin being used `BackboneReactMixin` creates a bridge of sorts that allows backbone functionality and reactjs functionality to coexist. getCollection is getting the backbone collection as per the understanding, and task_id in this case is being grabbed and output as expected, its when the functionality reaches the point of rendering `tasksListChild` where reach seems to just skip over it completely and continue on

Answer (score 0):

Will this work.

```js
_createTaskChild: function (model) {
        var taskID = model.get('task_id');
        console.log(taskID);
        return (
        <a className="list-group-item">
            <tasksListChild key={taskID} model={model} />
        </a>
        );
    }
```